# Change background color of a cell if not between two values and not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to change the color of a cell's background to red if the cell's value is not between 0.0086 and 0.0094, and also not blank. I have successfully covered the part less than 0.0086, but the other two conditions keep giving me errors. Below is my code thus far

```
=(($D$2:$D$1000) < 0.0086) AND (($D$2:$D$1000) >  0.0096) AND NOT(ISBLANK(($D$2:$D$1000)))
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=OR(D1<0.0086,D1>0.0094,D1="")
```

applied to $D$1:$D$1000.

(What you want rather than what you don't want may be conceptually easier.)

Based on body of question rather than Title.

Edit to exclude blank cells from highlighting:

```
=AND(OR(D1<0.0086,D1>0.0094),D1<>"")
```

Comment: Ideally I would like all my data to be between 0.0086 and 0.0094, but blank cells were getting highlighted as well.

Comment: I do not want it highlighted.

Comment: Yeah. The issue is that you are referencing the specific cell D1, and not the first cell I start at, D2. So I changed your formula to use D2 instead of D1 and now it works for any cell.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got it to work is as follows:

1. Under Home, Styles, Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cell Rules, then Greater Than, and enter your desired value (.0094), specify that to be red fill
2. Under Home, Styles, Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cell Rules, then Less Than, and enter your desired value (.0086), specify that to be red fill
3. Under Home, Styles, Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cell Rules, then New Rule, then new rule, format cells that contain..., blanks, and specify that to be no fill (or white fill)

I believe pnuts answer would be more efficient for the computer to process, however.